# Does altering a stored procedure during peak times cause locks on the tables?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, locks

Does altering a stored procedure during peak hours cause the system to lock the tables while the new changes to the stored are made?

Is there a best practice on stored procedure altering?

Let me know thanks

Comment: What's the *actual* question? Have you encountered a performance issue? What is it? A stored procedure is just text. Modifying it won't lock the data. *Executing* it will. A modified stored procedure though is modified text that has to be recompiled into an execution plan. After the first compilation, the new execution plan will be reused.

Comment: Do you have a stored procedure that is so complex and use so often, that recompilation causes issues? In that case, you should simplify it. Post the stored procedure code. On the other hand, are you sure it's not the *execution* that causes locks? Have you checked the Activity Monitor when you experience problems?

Comment: Is your actual question about the impact of altering an existing stored procedure while it's being executed? The new version of the proc will be used for new executions but the original version will continue to be used by existing sessions running the proc until execution completes. The schema modification lock on the proc itself should be brief.

Comment: Thanks this does answer my question. Calling the stored proc and something failing would probably cause a lock not the action of actually just altering the stored proc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stored procedure is just text. Modifying it won't lock the data. Executing it will.

A modified stored procedure though is modified text that has to be recompiled into an execution plan. After the first compilation, the new execution plan will be reused.

(Community Wiki answer based on comment by Panagiotis Kanavos)